# Showing the difference between Primes

Tags: prime-numbers

I create a list of primes in table form... How do I generate and display the difference between the prime numbers in sequence?

```
In[1]:= Table[Prime[n], {n, 10}]
Out[1]= {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29}
```

expected output:

```
{1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6}
```

All help gratefully received.

Comment: Differences[Table[Prime[i], {i, 1, 10}]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the one way to do it.

```
Differences@Prime[Range@10]
```

Comment: Excellent - Thank you! 
Chuckle - I have once again confirmed I am an idiot.